# Can't change my table of contents title anymore

Tags: table-of-contents, acronyms

I have created a cls. file for my repport in order to modify the title of my table of contents, my list of acronyms, etc. Here was the code for my titles:

```
\renewcommand\contentsname{\vspace{-2.55cm} \centering \huge\bfseries Table of Contents}
\renewcommand\listfigurename{\vspace{-2.55cm} \centering \huge\bfseries List of Figures}
\renewcommand\listtablename{\vspace{-2.55cm} \centering \huge\bfseries List of Tables}
\renewcommand*{\acronymname}{List of Abbreviations}
```

This was working well but when I added the following code in order to write in different languages, just above this part, it doesn't work anymore.

```
\RequirePackage[LAE,LFE,T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage[greek,main=english]{babel}
\RequirePackage{CJKutf8}
\RequirePackage{arabtex}
\RequirePackage{utf8}

\newcommand{\greekLanguage}[1]{\selectlanguage{greek}#1\selectlanguage{english}}
\newcommand{\chineseLanguage}[1]{\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gbsn}#1\end{CJK*}}
\newcommand{\arabicLanguage}[1]{\setarab \fullvocalize \transtrue \arabtrue 
    \begin{RLtext}#1\end{RLtext}}
\setcode{utf8}
```

Thanks a lot for your answers.

Dylan

Comment: As always around here, please provide a full but minimal example others can copy and test you see exactly your problem. We cannot do much with sniplets like this. Additionally `\...name` macros are expected to be text only. Formatting does not belong there. Thirdly, where exactly are those redefinitions placed in your document?

Comment: Why change the `.cls` file when you can implement the changes via packages (`.sty` files), thus keeping a distinction between the basic `.cls` code and your additions, ammendments, enhancements.?